# Examples of poor review audits

Tags: discussion, review-audit, big-list, disputed-review-audits

Since threads about review audits seem to be turning up fairly frequently now, it seemed like a good idea to open a thread to collect examples of those audits where people failed but feel like they should not have.

This serves both the purpose of getting at least a small idea of the scale of this (ie, how often does it happen), and also means that we will potentially get information enough to suggest concrete changes to the algorithms used for picking the audit cases (if this seems necessary).

Comment: board of shame is a better name for this question

Comment: And for venting!  It's frustrating to spend time thinking about a post, only to be told that I've chosen the wrong answer.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones that too, without each person needing to vent having to open a new thread for it (assuming they actually see this one).

Comment: I seem to recall that it is possible to remove audits from the audit system -- this post could be useful for that. But I can't find the source. Is there anyone who can verify this?

Comment: I get quite a few, but they are glaringly obvious and quick to dismiss.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535020/different-types-of-set-theory is too broad for sure and to some extent lacks context.

Comment: It appears that the audits have now been redesigned - clicking close on an audit wasn't an automatic pass for me just now, but rather gave me a chance to click an option first.

Comment: While the thread is obviously useful as a way to vent frustration, seeing it  bumped repeatedly gets old. I think it would be better implemented as a chat room, similar to [Whining Room](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/421/whining-room) on Meta. Or just add the *(whining)* tag.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I agree. It was originally supposed to provide examples that could show how it might be improved, but it seems clear that this will not happen. And if you think it is annoying to see it bumped, consider getting a notification each time making you think "ahh, someone is speaking to me" only to see that it is just another answer to this question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You can ask SE to be disassociated from this thing; I'm sure that seeing the situation they'll honor the request at once.

Comment: Should we add the tag ([tag:big-list]) to this question ?

Answer (score 32):

Side complaint: I seem to be getting an awful lot of review audits, maybe one per five legitimate review requests.

If you are asking me to spend my time performing community service, I would prefer you not waste my time with pointless "fake" tasks.

Comment: That would definitely be excessive.

Comment: I too am getting a lot of them.

Comment: Recently the fake reviews have died down. Maybe I made it through some kind of "probationary period" with a ton of audits.

Answer (score 30):

The newest and one of the most ridiculous examples to date:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/109542

I failed this by clicking "add comment". That's right. You're not allowed to comment when you're being audited. I'm filing a bug report.

Comment: I just had [a similar experience](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/417127) trying to leave a Comment noting [Related Questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654478/calculate-limit-0f-nested-square-roots).  The audit complains: "Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting."

Answer (score 26):

I have failed a few. One interesting thing is that, for "close" audits at least, the system *lies* about the vote count, showing 0 instead of the actual vote count. Which seems to be counterproductive: it appears they change the vote count to encourage reviewers to evaluate the question independently, but then they criticize the reviewer being too independent and not realizing that a question with a high vote count should not be closed!

Now that I realize this, I don't fail them anymore, because I check the vote count of the real question first. One examples I have been presented this way was [A "non-trivial" example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471577/a-non-trivial-example-of-a-cauchy-sequence-that-does-not-converge)

Comment: Good idea. I took your suggestion to heart and found that a question I was supposed to review had been deleted, so selecting "close" earned me kudos for making the right choice. While I understand the reason behind audits, I think that on balance (at least for me) the chilling effect outweighs the didactic benefits.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what the system actually says if one fails the audit? EDIT: ok, I think that's the text shown at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/stop-look-and-listen?cb=1

Comment: @mau: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/stop-look-and-listen is one of them, but the message is slightly different depending on which type of review you were performning

Answer (score 19):

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508096/17596 showed up as a "first post" review. I found the animation far more distracting than helpful, so I downvoted (disagreeing, apparently, with fifteen folks who think it's the cat's meow). Review audit failed.

Comment: First post audits are the most ridiculous of the bunch! I've failed audits for leaving alone posts that, while not of the highest quality, had no actionable problems.

Comment: I just had to review the first post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578662/what-is-this-beauty-curve (with fake 0 score and fake user reputation). I added a comment because the OP made a significant change to the question and the thing was in front of me, but apparently adding a comment to a post that was better before an edit means I'm a bad auditor.

Answer (score 18):

I failed a review audit for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499560/why-is-the-continuum-hypothesis-believed-to-be-false-by-the-majority-of-modern-s) because I went to close it as duplicate as I recognised the title and content of the post so thought it was an exact duplicate of itself (the review had artificially made it appear that the question was written 2 hours ago). This highlights a flaw in the system in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

The first time I got an audit, I thought it was a good idea. Well, not anymore.

I've failed some when we changed the policy, initiated by - I believe - [this topic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11075/78926). Since the new "close" reason was included, I go for it almost on every question that was nominated for closing and lacks any context or effort (i.e., *copy/paste* questions). I myself nominate such questions for closing if there was a request for edit in the comments and the OP didn't respond in a few hours.

But, there are many questions, especially those that were asked before we took this more serious stand on *copy/paste* questions, that were upvoted quite nicely, so I've expected to fail each such audit.

Because of that, like Carl, I now open almost every question in new tab, and check that it's not a trap. It's a pointless waste of time, but my alternative is to get "caught" simply for not agreeing with other voters of *that time*, possibly before the new "close" reason was added (when I myself voted against closing such questions, due to the lack of a proper "close" reason).

The alleged purpose of the audits is to force reviewers -- actually **voters**, which is important! -- to pay attention. But that's the problem! As the [site's help says](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (my emphasis):

> Our sites are all intended to be a **sort of representative democracy**. Moderator elections are an important part of that plan, but voting on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the **community governs the site** on a day to day basis. Every user with sufficient reputation can exercise their **right to vote**, every day that they visit the site.

In a *representative democracy*, people vote according to their personal views. Be it for the views different than those of a majority, or simply for being lazy, a voter in a *representative democracy* is allowed to vote differently than the majority. That is the core of a democratic system, and audits measure how close a person's vote is to that of a majority, punishing those who are not in accordance. Completely antidemocratic, and so anti-self-description of the site. I don't mind strict rules, but then don't make audits based on votes which can be -- and often are -- not in accordance with those.

If lazy voters are a problem, then all the incentive should be removed from such voting, i.e., badges. Who wants to help the community, doesn't need badges; those who vote for those little coloured circles won't do it anymore if those "medals" are gone.

But the system, as it is, is rotten. IMO, of course.

**Edit:** I forgot... I sometimes click "close" not to actually vote for it, but to see what did others select as the reason. Just "off-topic" from the description is not as specific as seeing which of these, which helps me focus on that particular reason and see if I consider it valid. An audit would "catch" me there as well.

Comment: +1 There is something distinctly pointy-haired about the whole audit system

Comment: @user7530 A perfect description! :-)

Answer (score 11):

I failed [this close-vote audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/102766). I wanted to vote to close it as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480003/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac1e1-frac1xxx), particularly since there was a comment on the original question suggesting it to be a duplicate. The suggested close reason was *not* as duplicate (I believe it may have been "too broad," but I don't recall exactly), but I do not agree that a close vote was inappropriate here.

Answer (score 9):

[This question post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3029083/9003) is a horrible "exemplar" of a post that *should be reopened,* according to a "reopen review queue audit."

In fact, the question should be put on hold, so the asker can improve it, and perhaps, and only then, reopened.

Including it as an exemplar of a post that users should reopen teaches users to reopen very poor posts, which is antithetical to the purpose of the reopen review queue.

The set of questions with a vote count of 5 or more, with no previous close votes, is not identical to the set of questions that should be reopened. The algorithm reflects the mistaken algorithms used in the review queue audits: high vote count greater than or equal to five net votes is not a reliable indicator of a good post.  (This is evident in many cases on point point: there exist a sizable percentage of former Hot Network Questions that received "popular" votes, not because the question is one that should be kept.)

Answer (score 8):

I just "failed" a reopen review audit. My philosophy is that the principle of res judicata applies to all reopen requests: that is, I will *automatically* reject any request to reopen a question that has not been edited since it was closed, unless strong reasons to reopen are given in the comments. The audit I failed showed no edits since closure and no comments at all. Although the question was allegedly closed as "unclear", I believed it to be actually closure-worthy as "off-topic: homework without a meaningful attempt" (although it turns out to have been answered by the asker some time later, so there's no actual need to close it). I just don't think that "no major problems" is a legitimate reason to reopen—if enough users voted to close, why should I substitute my judgement for theirs?

Comment: I disagree with your last line, in that sometimes closing is not clear cut. Perhaps starting a meta thread is appropriate when you come across debateable questions, but simply going "the first five people to the post held *this* opinion and who am I to question them?" isn't helpful. Although I do agree with the sentiment :-)

Comment: @user1729: Certainly closing is not always clear cut. But the notion that the second set of five people to consider it are inherently more likely than the first five to come up with the "correct" response is absurd. I haven't been around long enough to know whether comments on the question or a thread on meta are the better approach, but it certainly seems to me that *something* either in or surrounding the question should change before it is reconsidered. "Give me another chance at the lotto please" isn't a reason.

Comment: Yes notion that the second set of five people to consider it are inherently more likely than the first five to come up with the "correct" response is absurd, but so is the converse notion, that the first lot of people are inherently more likely than the first five to come up with the "correct" response. Also, when a question is in the reopen queue it is often because someone has voted for it to be reopened. So someone disagrees with the five. I believe their opinion should be considered.

Comment: @user1729: I think it's reasonable to require that they explain that opinion in order for in to be considered.

Comment: I would agree that an explanation would help, but I still think it is better to consider it than just to ignore it an pretend it hasn't happened.

Comment: I feel the "res judicata" reasoning is wrong, because one cannot vote to (re-)open before a question is closed. So it is not the first five people that voted to close, but just _some_ set of five people, among an unknown number of people who might have had other ideas. Also it is impossible to undo a close vote, I think even if the question _is_ edited (before it is closed).

Comment: Your *res judicata* doctrine is an abnegation of responsibility, pure and simple. And since you do assume the responsibility of adding your voice to close votes, you’re demonstrably biassed in favor of closing questions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I doubt you can see my close or reopen votes, but I take them all seriously. I feel great when I cast a reopen vote on a question I previously voted to close *because the OP went back and addressed the problems that led to closure*. When someone initiates a vote to reopen when nothing has changed, I think it's on them to explain why.

Comment: @dfeuer: I can see the ones that you make through the review queues, and I can see the close votes that I’ve been recording as I come across them, which in your case are the main source since I started paying close attention. Your last sentence is just more evidence of your bias in the matter, since the reason is obvious: that person did not think that the question should have been closed in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

I failed a First Post with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/517555/28900) for one of two reasons. I noticed two things at first glance:

1. There was a mix of unTeXified and TeXified variables.
2. The post mentioned that the numbers could be "very large," but didn't specify how large they could be, nor give much other context aside from "it's for a computer program."

What I intended to do (in some order) was to fix the mixed variables (which I have since done) and leave a comment to the effect of: "Out of curiosity, how large can $x$ and $y$ be? The best solution for you may depend on that, and on other context (like what sort of program this is for), so the more you can tell us, the better." I am not sure at this point whether I pressed 'edit' or 'add comment' first--I was too surprised to discover that I had failed. Once I failed and actually went to the question, of course, I discovered that I was not the only person who wondered how large the numbers $x,y$ could be--the $4$th comment down (at present) asks that very question, and there are other comments asking for more context.

Answer (score 8):

I rarely review, but I thought I'd give it a try, and almost immediately failed an audit.  I was presented with [a very poor answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853960/25554) in the “late answers” queue.  I opened the thread to which it was attached. I saw that the answer I was reviewing had been deleted several weeks ago, so I clicked the “no action necessary” button, and got this obnoxious response:

[image]

So that was a poke in the eye from the review system, and I will immediately return to my former practice of ignoring the review queue.

Answer (score 7):

[Probability and expectancy problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3027467/9003)

This is supposed to be a "reopen queue audit question" and to "pass" the audit, one is supposed to vote to reopen.

This is a problem statement question and deserves to be downvoted and closed, and not reopened!

Answer (score 6):

I failed this one. After the fact, I voted to close it and it has since been closed.

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/246038

It has no context or details. I hope the fact that it is now closed removes it from the review audit.

Comment: Now it will be moved from "known-good" to "known-bad" category, and used to trip up reviewers in the opposite direction. :)

Answer (score 6):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1056774

The entire question reads:

> Are there any necessary or sufficient condition for when in a general convex hexagon, the lines formed by joining the midpoints of opposite sides are concurrent (intersect in a common point)?

This question lacks context.  I can see that it *might* be interesting, but it appears entirely unmotivated to me.  Based on the single not-deleted answer, it appears that this might have originally been a contest problem (and an original source would be valuable context for future users who might be reading off of the same list of contest problems).  Frankly, not only do I think that this is a poor audit review question, I honestly think that it *should* be closed until the original asker provides some context.

Answer (score 5):

I failed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/133828) audit because I wanted it add a comment. Not that I added a  bad comment. For all any computer might know I wanted to say this problem is the best research direction for mathematics since the Langland's program. *Que sera sera*.

Answer (score 5):

I failed [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/687340/77151), ironically because I put too much effort into it. It was presented as a first post with 0 votes, on a question that had been answered 10 days ago. I navigated to the question and saw it had good answers v similar to the one I was reviewing so tried to add a comment to say it had already been answered => FAIL. (What I should have spotted was that I couldn't see the username of the answer I was reviewing on the page. And one of the answers was suspiciously <strike>similar</strike> identical to the one I was reviewing...:)

Anyway I was already thinking the review audit sucked and was wasting my time-- can't it at least adjust so that those who pass more audits get fewer in future? But when you fail them it's a disincentive to continue.

Comment: Here is the link to the review in question: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/175018

Answer (score 5):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1015074

This question is a fairly straight-forward "problem statement question" that I voted to close as "Lacking Context."  I think that the level of the material (advanced undergraduate or introductory graduate level complex analysis) coupled with the (non-obvious) difficulty of the problem earned it several upvotes, and I am willing to concede that the dan_fulea's answer may be one of the few instances of a great answer justifying the preservation of a question-of-debatable-merit (note that answers are invisible in the "Close Votes" review queue), but I don't think that this is a good audit question.

Answer (score 5):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1076507

The **entire** question reads:

> I have been stuck on this problem for hours and have absolutely no clue how to go about it. Any help would be amazing.

The question itself is in the title, and is a pretty standard combinatorics question.  I honestly don't understand how the question garnered five upvotes in the first place...

Answer (score 5):

Yesterday I failed [this Review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1191208), and when I posted an [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30146#30146) in the Reopen/Undelete thread, another user reported failing two [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1191114) [audits](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1191553), and someone else later failed [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1198603). That same person failed [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1198756) of the same type less than 6 hours later.

The number of such posts by the same user (who also had a question deleted on MO, though I can't see it), their frequency (all posted within a few days) and the fact that they all link to the same website is suspect, but taken in isolation they don't look so bad. So these make poor examples for review audits.

Comment: The weirdest thing is why the deletion happened **7 months later**.

Answer (score 5):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1480735

As far as I can see, the question is not visible in the audit link. The question is

[Prove this sequence converges to $1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887020/prove-this-sequence-converges-to-1-2)

There is a comment under the question providing a link to a duplicate. So, I voted to close as a duplicate and failed the review audit.

Answer (score 4):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/174827

I failed this audit, because I tried to mark it as a duplicate. 
The audit said it has been asked (I think) 1 hour ago and I was absolutely sure, that I have read exactly the same question a few days ago. However, I *had* read exactly this question before, because that *first post* was a fake of the orginal good question...

Comment: Indeed, it seems that a minimal change that ought to be made to this system is that clicking the "close" button is not an automatic failure, when selecting an inappropriate reason would be the actual failure (after all, you have not actually chosen an action by clicking the "close" button).

Answer (score 4):

I passed [this first post audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/177648) by selecting no action needed (which I think is the appropriate result). The question has $4$ close votes currently, but is sitting at $+17$; considering that at least $4$ relatively high-reputation users think that the question is unclear to the point it should be closed (while many other users disagree), it seems inappropriate to use this question to test the reviewer.

Answer (score 4):

I failed this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/512046

I understand that it is an interesting question that does provide a bit of background with a link to the problem. But there is no attempt at solving the problem, so I voted to close. Some will disagree on this, but the question doesn't (IMO) belong in the list of audit questions.

Answer (score 4):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/781215

I think this is a poor review audit. I voted to close as "too broad" because well...it's too broad! The first comment even says it's a "very broad question".

I voted to close as too broad outside of review queue. So hopefully it won't show up again.

Answer (score 4):

[Black holes and the Schwartzschild solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052107/black-holes-and-the-schwarzschild-solution)

This Question turned up in my Close Vote review (as an audit).  Because the Question garnered five upvotes, the system considers it a model of something that ought not be closed.  But despite the OP's declaration, "This is probably more a mathematical problem as far as I can see...", it was [cross-posted to Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450294/radius-of-star-the-schwarzschild-metric-and-black-holes) and consists of four sub-queries that, judging by the OP's comments under the Question, have a strong nexus with the physics of gravitational fields.

The OP accepted the lengthy Answer (with references) that was given at Physics.SE and did not accept either of the Answers given to the Math.SE version.  Therefore I feel this really should be closed as off-topic here.  Those interested in the subject matter will still be able to follow links to the Physics.SE post (no migration is required).

Answer (score 4):

I got this one:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1194064

I passed it by leaving it open, but it seems not nearly clear-cut enough to qualify as a good review audit. The asker has not provided much in the way of evidence of effort.

I also floated this in a [discrete Meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/where-do-i-dispute-review-audits?noredirect=1#comment130235_30187), before posting here.

Answer (score 4):

[Are there any properties of sup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1397426)

The question title is not informative, and suggests a very broad question (rather than the fairly focused question which is actually presented).  The question itself reads:

> Can I say: 
>   $$\sup |f(x)-h(x)+g(x)-g(x)| = \sup|f(x)-g(x)|+ \sup|g(x)-h(x)|$$
>
> I can't seem to find any properties of $\sup$ , so i am wondering if there is any properties that we can generalize to sup of some functions restricted on domain $x \in [0,1]$ for example

This question is (to me) unclear.  I don't know if the asker is trying to prove this identity (which isn'g going to be possible), or if they are looking for conditions under which the identity will hold.

It may be worth noting that I am not the only one to have been stung by this audit:  https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1395894 .

Comment: Yep, not a sound exemplar for a review audit.

Answer (score 4):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1407444

Even if we accept that questions may be appropriately answered with hints (and the consensus seems to be that hint answers are okay in certain circumstances), it is not at all clear to me that this is, in fact, a good hint.  I can see definite differences of opinion about the quality of this answer or its appropriateness for Math SE.  As such, it seems like a poor choice for audits.

Comment: I agree with you.  This would have been a good Comment, and if intended to provoke a Socratic dialog, perhaps Robert could be cajoled to add something more to the post.

Answer (score 4):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1408914

The question is *long* but, at the end of the day, it is nothing more than a statement of a result which the asker wants proved.  There is no additional context.  This is even pointed out [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696290/let-a-in-mathbbr2-times-2-and-assume-that-rm-tra4-prove-or-dispr#comment7596301_3696290):

> It would be helpful if you could share some of your thoughts on the problem: Where did you encounter the problem; do we have a reason to suspect that this problem has a nice solution? What have you tried? How far did you get before you got stuck? Are there any results/techniques that you suspect would be applicable here? — Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Though not a major one. I tried to edit the ${\boxed {tea+wine=s}}$ into ${\boxed {\text{tea+wine=s}}}$ and the one following -> (s-wine)...And I failed.

Comment: $\text{The funny part is, I figured out it's a review test, and still, failed...}$

Comment: And so far, 2 others like me https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3910635/timeline

Answer (score 3):

Failed this audit: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/141607

I call BS; this is an adequate (if short) answer and I would in fact upvote it in preference to the accepted answer, if it hadn't been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Although this thread seems fairly quiet now, I have to report this one:

[Review Close Votes - Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/504724)

Although the Question has problems, these are not currently of the *unclear what you are asking* variety.  No doubt the Question was properly closed and downvoted on that account, but subsequently it was edited in a way that makes the problem posed clear and precise.

I bring it up, not to argue for reopening, but to point out that the criteria for Review Audits do not seem to take into account post closure edits, other than to presumably require that the item remains closed currently.

Comment: Almost the same happened to me. The question had problems, probably leading to a close, but was market as "unclear what you are asking". Nevertheless, the question was so, so clear that somebody commented the answer. I suppose I had to vote for the formatting issues without considering anything else...

Comment: @RafaBudría:  If it's simply formatting, I often try to fix them and reopen, though in some cases the edit preview flummoxes me and I fail.  More dubious are cases that might be closed for lack of context.  Sometimes, if I think the Question is of genuine interest, I vote to reopen despite that lack.

Answer (score 3):

Just got this one:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/532401

The question shows no effort, starts out with "community, I need to solve the following problem" and then ends with (bold face) "I try several ways, and the hint given below but I have no luck to overcome this problem, I hope someone knows how to do it. It will be really appreciated if someone knows the actual proof, I'd like to learn how did they arrived that such a series converges. Thanks, and I will give some of my reputation for the actual proof. Thanks to all the community" Give me a break.

Comment: Did you happen to notice who last edited it?

Comment: Meh. The annoying bold stuff could be edited out. And the question does have some redeeming qualities to offset the perceived lack of effort.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22071

Comment: @DanielFischer Ha, no I did not. I don't think that makes any difference.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, I just found it amusing.

Answer (score 3):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1068861

The question is about the boundedness of manifolds embedded in Euclidean space, with closed curves being the motivating example.  The answer reads

> How is your definition of closed curve? If it just a continuous image of $S^1$ then it is compact, so bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$

This would be appropriate for a comment (specifically, it appears that the answer is asking for clarification about what is meant by a "closed curve", then addresses only that part of the question).

Comment: However it does assume a choice of definition and answer, in admittedly terse fashion favored by some, the part of the Question raised in the title.  Of course it is far from a true first post, which is irksome.

Comment: @hardmath I am not trying to argue that the answer is terrible as an answer (it is pretty borderline if you ask me, and my reaction in the review queue was that it *should* have been a comment, not an answer, hence I flagged it as such, but I agree that it is a close call).  My complaint is that it is terrible as a review audit.  Review audits are supposed to be unambiguous, and are meant to ensure that people are actually reading what they review and not just click-click-clicking.

Answer (score 3):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1140429

This question, while it is nicely typeset and all, asks two questions at once. Therefore it should be closed as "too broad". ("Avoid asking multiple questions at once.")

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605941/proving-that-a-point-is-a-midpoint) queston in the Reopen Queue. I voted to leave closed, as it needs details; as it stands it's just a problem statement. Unfortunately I failed the audit, and I was supposed to vote to reopen. I disagree strongly enough to post this here.

Answer (score 3):

[Basis-free, field-independent definition of determinants?](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/1819173)

I got a "STOP! Look and Listen." for attempting to mark it as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/is-there-a-definition-of-determinants-that-does-not-rely-on-how-they-are-calcula). The irony is that this question was actually closed as a duplicate with the same question I suggested as a dupe target, and then reopened. I disagree with the reopening, but in any case I don't think the audit system should choose questions that had been closed before.

Comment: More to the point, marking a question as a duplicate should not count as a "negative" action for the purposes of failing an audit.  It is entirely compatible with a question being very high quality!

Answer (score 2):

I passed this one (the alleged closure reason was "too broad", which it's not, and the score was artificially $0$), but [Monoids with left common multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470526/monoids-with-left-common-multiples) actually does lack context. What is the source of the OP's intuition (is there a special case where this holds)? What did they try?

Comment: I think *'So this is a result which I think is true but have yet to find a quick proof for.'* constitutes enough context. It may not be question of the year, but it's far from a PSQ.

Comment: @DanielRust, I don't see how stamping words like that onto the end of a PSQ make it anything more than a PSQ.

Comment: I've had a few now with alleged closure reasons which don't fit but which should be closed for lacking context. Most recently [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/503343/5676).

Comment: @Peter: Fortunately, André got there first.

Answer (score 2):

Today I was asked to review an answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701218/show-phi-is-a-homomorphism). The answer I was to review has been deleted. The deleted answer stated that the real number group may be equipped with the operation "$+$". I was warned that this was a bad answer. I am supposed to click the "I understand button." This I will refuse to do. It seems to me that is is an excellent hint for the problem.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a good answer (although I completely understand not clicking the "I understand button." I generally refuse to): I read it as a new question separate from the post, not a hint towards the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I failed [this reopen audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/235228). The question was closed as "unclear," although I think it's perfectly clear what's being asked (and contains some initial thoughts from the OP about the issue).

Answer (score 2):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/929400

The system claimed it's marked with *unclear what you're asking*, but I voted to close this question for *off topic* due to the question writer's lack of response to another user's question "What did you try? ..."

Answer (score 2):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/959283

I failed this Review Audit for the Close queue, but curiously it seems a different user is shown passing it!  However I'm using it to call attention to the mechanism of changing the imputed Close Reason.

The Question had been closed as *unclear what you are asking* but shows in review as (potentially) *too broad*.  While one might agree that asking something which is essentially an immediate application of the defintion (Why is the sequence of Fibonacci numbers countable?) leaves Readers wondering what the problem is really asking, it is clearly something that can be answered (and was) in brief but detailed fashion.

I just wanted to point out the strange alteration of the actual close reason.  It seems to me many "false negative" reviews use *primarily opinion based* as the proposed close reason, which I suspect is one of the least actually used reasons, and "too broad" strikes me as a less rare but still infrequent case.

Answer (score 2):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/1225713

The question is asking for references.  A reference is given, with enough context to know that the answerer has not read the book themselves, but found the table of contents useful.  This is not a *great* answer, but is certainly *an* answer to the question, and not poor enough (in my opinion), to be considered a "low quality answer".  Frankly, the question is the problem, not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got this one: [Maximal value of dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596800/maximal-value-of-dimension). I voted to close because of "his question is missing context or other details".

Answer (score 1):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/929848

It came up as a first post and I intended to close it, either as *unclear what you're asking*, or as *off-topic*.

The problem itself is terribly worded, as most answers discuss. The question also shows no thoughts or effort whatsoever.

Turns out it has 24 upvotes.

Comment: The question looks fine to me. "The problem itself is terribly worded" is the reason why the question was asked in the first place, so I don't understand this complaint. "The question also shows no thoughts or effort whatsoever." Effort and thoughts are not a requirement for questions here. We sometimes ask this for problems that look like homework, but from the first sentence of the question, it is clear that this is not the case.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Ok, perhaps the wording is not the issue here. But I disagree about lack of context. I thought that **every** question lacking at least minimal effort should be closed as off-topic and I have been reviewing accordingly. People downvote and request OP's thoughts on every such question. Could you please link to a source for your claim: "Effort and thoughts are not a requirement for questions here." I'm aware that it is sometimes a grey area, of course. If I'm wrong, I'm happy to be convinced otherwise.

Comment: See the discussion [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23169). You'll also note that a lot of discussion re: effort is about homework exercises (which this question is not). You should also notice how many well received questions there are with no effort to solve them by the asker ([here's](//math.stackexchange.com/q/1886054) one of David Speyer's). For the question in the review, I'm at a loss for what sort of effort could even be provided to a question of "this doesn't make sense, what does it mean?"

Comment: If you're still not convinced, consider opening a new question on meta so the discussion gets more attention. I would also be interested in seeing what other people think.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Ok, thank you. I'm actually a bit relieved because I found the "show your effort" policy a bit too strict myself, but I thought that is the way things are done here.

Answer (score 1):

I've commented on an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3171079/649368) to a question about [division by zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3171071/649368) from a person in the 9th grade saying that the answer may be hard to understand by the OP and I failed because I should have not commented.

I suggest that this specific answer is removed from the test list.

Answer (score 1):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1201934

I voted to close the question as being "Too Broad."  In general, I think that questions beginning "What kinds of mathematics can be done with [insert topic here]?" are not really good for this site (I'm curious---is there a consensus on this?).  Even if the community ultimately feels that this question is appropriate, I don't think that it is a good audit question.

Answer (score 1):

I failed this audit today:

> [Is $x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_{2020}^2=-1$ solvable in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1398600)

This post is a standard example of problem-statement questions with no context such as what the OP has tried and where the question comes from, yet it received 5 up votes and was put into review audit. I have cast a closure vote on it.

Answer (score 1):

[This question appeared in the low quality review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700638/real-world-application-where-strong-lln-is-needed-weak-lln-is-not-enough), and I failed the audit because I voted to close the question.  I was instructed "You should have said "looks okay"."

The question is not okay.  It includes no context, no considerations from the OP, nothing, just a question asking others to give them the desired example/counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

This question from nine years ago no longer represents an appropriate audit post, given it demands a user to conclude "looks okay", in order to pass the audit:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1709668

---

My comments:  This does not exemplify a good question, as it violates the quality standards of the site, and is no longer valid as a representative of a post no one should close.

This post was acceptable, at the time it was posted, so I do not seek it's closure/deletion.   But it needs to be removed from the pool of review audits.

Comment: I believe the timeline of a post has an entry for whenever the post is used for an audit, but curiously this post's [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/248970/timeline) does not have any such entry. Perhaps this is a bug? (Of course, that is tangential to whether the post makes for a good audit or not.)

Answer (score 0):

Latest dubious audit question: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/202870

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I failed this [audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/518212) in the following way : The answer was presented as a *First Post*. I spent some time to understand the chain of ideas and conclude that it is a mathematically correct answer. Although I estimated (and still do) that it deserves more explanations. I don't believe it would be accepted either as an answer in a school test not in a peer-review article. As it was presented as a First Post, it is logical to react and ask for improvement. Therefore I wrote a comment and got the "STOP ! Look and listen" message before I could select to keep the answer.

Comment: While I disagree with your assessment of the answer, it is definitely problematic that merely writing a comment is considered an incorrect action.

Comment: @EricWofsey. The other comments were not available during the audit. Some of them tend to agree that the answer could have been more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Question link: [Proving $x^2+x+1\gt0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834495/proving-x2x1-gt0)

Review link: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1042494

Screen capture:

[image]

When I got to this question, I actually opened up the post to see the score and the close votes of the post (I almost always do that when reviewing, unless the post is really bad and obviously deserve to be closed).

However, although this question is well-received, I think that this question is pretty much opinion-based, as it asks for as many ways to prove $x^2+x+1>0$ as possible.

I decided to vote to close as "primarily opinion-based" and of course I failed the audit, luckily I hadn't failed any other audits in the last 30 days.

At this point, I'm not really sure if there is a "close vote guidelines" about this type of questions that ask "as many ways as you can think of", or maybe I'm a bit too strict.

Comment: I don't see how a request for a list of different ways of proving a given result can be interpreted as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: I probably think so too, after seeing the highest-rated question here: "Visually stunning math concepts which are easy to explain".

Answer (score 0):

I failed an audit regarding an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3345600) to the question "Is there a name for categories whose objects are sets?" because I thought that the answer was short and I commented asking to expand it a bit.

In my case, the comment was not negative and it was within the usual scope of the comments: to ask for more information.

Furthermore, I based my reasoning on the fact that the question was present for almost a month, and in these cases I think that it is even more important that the answer should be more detailed to benefit other users besides the original poster.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a problem with the audit *item*, so much as it is a problem with the audit *system*, which considers commenting to be bad form.  Frankly, I think that commenting should *always* be considered a reasonable action from the point of view of auditing. :\

Answer (score 0):

This one: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/1522462

> Angle 30 can be constructed, through drawing an equilateral triangle, constructing angle 120, bisecting it multiple times and getting angle 30. Is it possible to contruct 3 degrees using geometric theorems and how?

The solution being reviewed reads essentially "A pentadecagon is constructible, and after you bisect its 24-degree slices 3 times, you get 3-degree angles."

The "right answer" is that it is very poor quality.

I beg to differ. The worst anyone could say for this is that it is not totally self-contained, but I think we'd all agree the construction of a regular pentadecagon is unnecessary. It is concise, workable, and on the same level as the asker's context.

Answer (score 0):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/1736611

The audit system considers this a good question, presumably because both the question itself and its top answer are highly upvoted. However this question clearly lacks focus, so I flagged it as lacking focus and failed the audit.

It contains at least three questions, (1) what is an elementary example of a coalgebra; (2) how to define a coalgebra without the language of category theory; (3) what is a comultiplication, and why is it the dual of the multipliation. In addition to these, it also includes a side question about how to "de-categorify" a definition. While an expository article about coalgebras can probably answer all these questions to OP's satisfaction (indeed the top answer seems to be exactly that), the question itself still lacks focus and should be pared down.

Comment: I agree with you.  The algorithm used by the software looks for >5 upvotes, no close votes, assuming all such questions and answers are good models.  As you note, this is not always the case.  Sometimes, when encountering such poor models of a good question, a mere close vote is all that is needed to prevent it from continued presence as an audit.

Answer (score -1):

[Another gem](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/132926). The question was whether to close it as unclear, and the answer was clearly *no* — the OP is explicitly asking how to construct such a completion. This was so obvious that I foolishly didn’t bother to check the original. It turns out that the line *How might I go about this?* was added by someone else, and the original question *was* genuinely unclear.

Answer (score -1):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1242652

I actually think that this question is interesting, but it suffers a bit from being overly broad.  I voted to keep it, but can see the other side of the argument, as well.  I don't think that it is a good audit question, as there is a reasonable argument which could be made in favor of closure.

Answer (score -1):

I failed the audit in the "Close" review queue when asked about this [question post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525473).

After the revisions, it already demonstrates the asker's effort. It should no longer be closed actually, but I'm not confident in the re-opening process so posting here anyway.

[image]

Comment: No one else voted to reopen and there's at least one person disagreeing here on this meta via downvote, so it seems that I'm misunderstanding something. Perhaps people think the math is just fundamentally wrong so it should remain closed, but I was trying to say that IF the close reason was "needs details or clarity" then it was already fixed via edit. Getting the basic math wrong (misunderstanding the definition of a limit) might deserve some downvotes as well as removal from the system, but I don't see how closing as "needs details or clarity" is the proper course.

Answer (score -2):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/231217

This is a badly-written question, no doubt about it, and it deserves its downvotes. But I disagree that this question should be closed (except perhaps as a duplicate), and strongly disagree that the close is so clear-cut that it should be included as a review audit. After all, an identical question got 20 upvotes on Mathoverflow...

Comment: Link to MO question?

Comment: @Did http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16991/what-are-the-connections-between-pi-and-prime-numbers

Comment: The questions are hardly identical: the MO version provides two specific suggestions, the MSE none.

Comment: @Did So asking, "I've heard 2 and 5 are prime numbers. What are more examples of prime numbers?" is hardly identical to "What are some examples of prime numbers"? The former shows more conscientiousness and effort, perhaps, but beyond that I'm afraid I don't agree.

Comment: I think the question on MSE is bad because it's not at all clear why the asker believes that there is a connection between pi and primes (I think there is, but need help with proof), nor even at all what they mean by "direct link." In the MO question, it was fairly clear what was being asked, IMHO.