# Allow question to be closed for low effort

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, homework, context

I do like helping people out on exercises but I see way too many questions with little to no effort in trying to solve. I think these people are just asking to get their assignments done. I don't think it is very ethical for the whole community to help them because they were assigned those questions so they could learn.

Anyways I propose that an option which pops up in the close menu should be 'low effort homework'.

Secondly, I'd like there to be some standard posts now some basic concepts like solving certain kinds of the question because I've seen waayyyyyy too many questions which asks type of question which the most basic idea which anyone who has even remotely done the topic could solve.

For example of what I'm talking about, see how [they do it on chemistry stack exchange here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/an-introduction-to-oxidation-state-oxidation-number)

Comment: [mhmm?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions)

Comment: As you may be aware, it's common practice for such questions to be closed under one or the other of the two "lacks context or details" clauses.   "Context", of course, serves as a bit of a catch-all which is, I think, intended to capture not only a lack of effort but a clear indication of the users background and, relatedly, the tools which are meant to be available.  "details" I take to reflect a desire for something more substantial than "I have no idea what to do."

Comment: I have added some tags which seemed suitable to me - for example ([meta-tag:homework]) and ([meta-tag:context]) seem to be related to your question. Of course, if you prefer a different choice of tags, do not hesitate to edit them further.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

About the first part of your question (about low effort posts) - this is exactly what the "missing context" close reason is for. (Of course, *context* is wider than just effort - there are also other ways to include context than just own attempts at the problem. A reasonable explanation what is meant by context can be found in the "[Provide Context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#9960)" section in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)) See also: [New changes to close reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31544). You can find some other related links in the  [corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/context/info).

It is worth mentioning that there used to be a close reason called homework, it was [removed in 2013](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/guideline-for-using-lack-of-context-and-homework-close-reasons/11693#11693). There also was a tag called [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), which was [removed in 2014](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what).

---

For the second part about *standard posts*, you can check the posts on the main which are tagged [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) and also the lists collected here on meta such as: [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868), [Catalog of limits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16717) and [Catalog of standard exercises](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16708). (I have tried something similar for a few specific topics here: [Would “organizer posts” be useful/welcome here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3967#4071) But as you can see, so far there are only three such posts listed there.)

But even the lists created automatically by the software can serve this purpose - if you check the frequent tab of some tag, you can see there questions which appear frequently, so they are in a way "standard questions" in the given tag. (This is what you get [in the calculus tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus?sort=frequent). You can look at [frequent questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Frequent) in general - without choosing a specific tag. But if you're interested in a specific topic, restring this by the choice of the tag might help.) Do not forget to switch from frequent back to your preferred view when you browse the site further.