# I failed an audit, and I don't understand why.

Tags: support, review-audit

I was reviewing some close votes and there came a question which was marked as "primarily opinion based". But obviously it is not. However, I thought the question should be closed for some other reason, so I chose "close" in the options.

And then it showed that the question is an audit, and it said that I failed the audit.

Well, I guess it doesn't hurt much for me to fail an audit. But I just want to know if there is any way I could object to the decision. I can do nothing but pressing that "I understand" buttom, while I don't really understand why.....

Comment: When I fail the audit and didn't agree with the "I understand" button. I simply close that browser window.

Comment: Would you tell us why you want to close it?

Comment: @Phira: Well, a standard one. The OP didn't provide enough information on what the background he/she had and what did he/she tried in the problem. The question is linked in Mad Scientist's answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of poor review audits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About your question:

> [is] there is any way I could object to the decision.

I guess one could say that you already did object by starting this meta thread. But, the answer you are looking for is (probably)no, there is no way to appeal the failed audit. (As a side note I would agree that there should be The best thing might be to post the audit in this list

[Examples of poor review audits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits)

Answer (score 5):

The audits use real questions from the site, [the question your audit used](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781214/smallest-k-for-which-sin2x-sin2y-le-kx-y-holds) has a score of +6 and isn't closed.

The audits fail to work if the community doesn't moderate consistently, if questions that arguably should be closed are often staying open and receive upvotes, the audits are inevitably going to be problematic.

The audit system avoids controversial questions as far as I understand, so if a few users had downvoted or voted to close that question it wouldn't have been picked by the system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually that didn't answer my question. I know that question has a +6 vote, but I still think that it should be closed (or I will not ask here ^^). I really want to know if there is any way I could object the decision, and then my objection would go through some kinds of process and come up with another decisions to decide whether or not the question would be used again as an audit.

Comment: @John If you vote to close the question (outside the audit) and enough users agree this should remove the question from the audit pool. There is no way to dispute failed audits, though.

Comment: "There is no way to dispute failed audits, though." Well, there's always the International Court of Justice at The Hague.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Justice only matters when there is a sentence that matters. As the sentencing here is basically non-existent, I see no real issue here...