# How are review audit questions picked?

Tags: support, review, review-audit

It appears so to me this is the case and the system decides whether it is a good question by number of votes the question it receives. Can someone please confirm thus?

The reason is that I got this question for a review check. It had 5 upvotes but I would close it as off-topic, thus I got a stop and pay attention message.

[How to prove a series converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822602/how-to-prove-a-series-converge)

Comment: Here is [link to the review audit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/234458) mentioned in the post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak i never knew this was called a review audit. Good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread [Examples of poor review audits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10924/147263) contains other such examples. Yes, the review audits are picked automatically, based on the data like score, post history (close/delete events)  and maybe the number of views, who knows. The algorithm is not disclosed.

Naturally, decisions to close or not to close are not a function of question score. One can sincerely believe that a popular question should have been closed, and get blamed  for not paying attention. This is neither  more nor less  than a little annoyance and loss of time.

For Close review specifically, I tend to  open most questions in a new tab and hit Skip in review; then vote on the question directly. (This process can be  streamlined by [bookmarklets](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC)). E.g., "known bad" audit questions are already deleted, so I don't have to waste time picking a close reason for them.  This also allows me to review more than $20$ questions from Close queue per day. (Cue meta outrage about exploiting a loophole.)

Comment: algorithm not disclosed! that is what I was curious about. thanks.

Comment: Apparently the algorithm doesn't even take current close-votes into account. I posted an answer in that thread about a question that was (according to the algorithm) supposed to be left open, but it had *four* close-votes on it.