# Where do I dispute review audits?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I have a review audit that I'd like to dispute:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1194064

I passed this particular audit by leaving it open, but it wouldn't surprise me if someone voted to close this question for lack of context.

Is there a particular place to dispute review audits? Or do we expect a new Meta question each time?

Comment: Why are you unwilling to close it if it has received good answers? (deletion is another matter) Or do you think the review audit is faulty and the question deserves to be closed?

Comment: @YuiToCheng What do you mean?

Comment: OK, I don't understand what you mean by "dispute"... You can't skip it?

Comment: @YuiToCheng I'm disputing it on the grounds that it is not a clear-cut case, either for closure or for leaving open. Review audits shouldn't come down to such a close personal judgement call.

Comment: Why not skip it? Btw, [Examples of poor review audits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits?r=SearchResults&s=2|73.7770) is the place to post poor review audits.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Skipping doesn't help clear the queue. If everyone skips the edge cases, then it takes ages for the question to leave the queue, and the question's fate is decided by the zealots.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Ah awesome. I just tagged the question [meta-tag:disputed-review-audit].

Comment: It's better to link the review itself, rather than the question itself.