# Failed an audit, but I have my doubts about it.

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I failed this [audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1198603). However, I am not exactly sure why the answer to a book-suggestion question with a book suggestion is wrong. Can anyone explain what is the standard procedure for such answers?

I just failed another audit: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1198756 and this seems perfectly legitimate in my opinion.

Comment: [This is relevant](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today/30146#30146). I've failed tons of book recommendation review audits. All of them are deleted by Community as spam or offensive.

Comment: I've added your case to [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits/30150#30150). In short, these posts are not too bad invidually, but apparently this user posted a lot of them.

Comment: The second fail is probably due to the fact that the entire answer is copied from the description of the book in the link and seems to be, at least mildly, condescending. I think it's spam, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer says among other things:

> This is a great book for you to understand when to use certain concepts, equations, and tables. This is a very good introductory text into thermodynamics for undergraduate students.

That's a bit peculiar as a recommendation for a book on differential equations. Sure some DE might be used in thermodynamics but still that description is not in line with the question.

The answer is somewhat subtle spam, there to place the link. Thus, the audit is not  'wrong', but it's one that is easy to miss.

The second is even more tricky in isolation. It does not look like a good answer, but yes one could let it pass.

Note that review-audits are not selected manually, but automatically, thus it's hard to avoid the occasional corner case.

Comment: One thing that's very easy to miss on an audit is that there was not only one such post : see [my answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits/30150#30150) to the "failed audits" thread.

Comment: Do I fail an audit if I opt to skip?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan no, it's not problem to skip an audit. If you skip audits all the time this might be a red flag though. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253003/what-happens-if-i-skip-a-review-audit for reference.

Comment: Ok, because I am not an expert on any topic and know enough to hold an opinion on very few topics. So I avoid questions and answers that do not seem to have any apparent problems.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I added some more remark.