# Audit on demand for review queues

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-audit, privileges

I have just gained queues access privilege (500 reputation), so I can review First Answers, First questions and Late answers on main website. I'm willing to help these queues alongside the community and I hope to make wise decisions.

However, I'm still a newbie, and I am wondering if there is any possibility to automatically trigger the review audit on myself, just for the purpose of training and testing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could look at the review by other users and comparing with what you would do - it's not the same as a review audit, but it is something. Users with sufficient reputation can see complete review history [in each queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/history), but any user can see reviews [using SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1272909/recent-reviews-of-a-specific-type?type=5). (And also reviews [by a specific user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews) on the site.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak That is a great hint, and a great app you made! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You can try to add a comment and it might say “This question is an audit” and not let you comment. The review also might say “Our systems have automatically detected this as spam, so please review carefully”. These are two ways to know if there is an audit.

Comment: @TymaGaidash, it is not about bypassing audits, but triggering them.

Comment: Don't trigger an audit; they're not useful for this purpose. They're not supposed to help train you to determine what does or doesn't meet standards, they're just automatically-picked examples of deleted, down-voted, and closed questions, supposedly as a "no-brainer" choice to close (which they sort of do work, [sometimes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/examples-of-poor-review-audits)). Basically, when they work, they aren't testing the subtleties of deciding when to close questions, and when they aren't working, then any conclusions drawn will be erroneous.

Comment: @Theo  Similarly, supposedly highly upvoted (5 or more) require a "Keep open" response, or one fails the audit.  They work with predefined standards by SE to fail or pass an audit.  Some poor posts good legitimately be voted to remain open; but likewise some highly upvoted posts don't necessarily meet site requirements.  But I agree with your last sentence whole-heartedly.